# Do universities employ teachers?

Tags: teaching

Do universities employ people simply to teach?

I come from a family of teachers, so teaching comes naturally to me. What worth would a university put on a person that is willing to take a large amount of the teaching load?

Would certain departments employ people who are willing and able to do the teaching, leaving other members of faculty to do other things or is teaching just simply not a big enough part of a university's work to justify employing people specifically for it?

Comment: Anecdotal, but yes. At my university there exist teaching fellows whose main job is undergraduate teaching (they have some time for their own research over the summer and take on service roles too). These people all hold PhDs in the relevant subject.

Comment: Do they exist at small unis as well?

Comment: My university has around 10,000 undergraduates, so yes (I think that counts as a pretty small uni).

Comment: In general, consider teaching at a community college where teaching is emphasized more than research. E.g., CUNY has Lecturer positions which are all teaching (plus service), requiring no research.

Comment: Which field? It matters.

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Comment: Adjunct faculty is somewhat like this kind of position. Not necessarily ideal job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, research universities hire full-time faculty whose primary job is teaching.  At least in the US, these faculty typically have different titles from tenure-track faculty, such as instructor, lecturer, senior lecturer, and teaching (assistant/associate/full) professor.  For example, my department employs 12 lecturers and teaching [*rank*] professors; my wife is one of 13 lecturers in another department.  We work at a large R1 state university; both our departments also have *lots* of "standard" tenure-track faculty.

Teaching faculty in my department are primarily responsible for the large lower-division undergraduate courses.  To first approximation, each such class is taught and maintained by the same teaching faculty member every semester.  In contrast, tenure-track faculty like me normally bounce between a few different courses, including upper-division requirements, electives, and graduate classes.  Teaching faculty in my department typically teach 3-5 times as many students per semester as tenure-track faculty, mostly because our intro classes are *huge*.  Most teaching faculty also have teaching-related service responsibilities, like serving on curriculum revision, grievance, and appeal committees.

At most R1 universities, including mine, teaching faculty are ineligible for tenure. But there are exceptions, like Berkeley's "[Lecturers with Security of Employment](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ddgarcia/SOE.html)" or Duke's "[Professors of the Practice](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/)".

Comment: Another example for last paragraph: CUNY's ["Lecturer with Certificate of Continuous Employment"](http://www.psc-cuny.org/rights/certificate-continuous-employment-cce).